# Oralce10 retag request

Tags: support, retag-request

Please burninate and blacklist [oralce10](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oralce10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need - I've just retagged the question and the dodgy tag will disappear at some point

Comment: midnight tonight UTC if no Q have it, supposedly.